# Migration from Rackspace IMAP to local exchange 2010 server?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, migration, imap

as we switch from our rackspace apps e-mail mailboxes to a local exchange 2010 server, i'm looking for a working way to migrate all mailbox from IMAP to exchange mailboxes. i already tried using `imapsync` and drag'n'drop mailboxes from one imapa ccount to the other, but both ways take ages or fail because of the mailbox sizes. each mailbox has about 10gig of mail.

is there any solution which can convert .mbox files to exchange directly on the server?

there's a migration tool by microsoft "Microsoft Transporter Suite", but the dropped support for exchange 2010.

do you have best pratice solutions? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1 Spend some money:**

I would try [Aid4Mail](http://www.aid4mail.com/) to convert massive amounts of `.mboxes` to `.pst's` for importing in to Exchange. I have used this recently with great success.

At a $40 price tag it is relatively cheap. I hate spending money on software when I don't have to, but sometimes you have to bite the bullet if you want something down in a time effective manner, which it sounds like you do.

**Option 2 spend a lot of time:**

If you do not feel like spending $40 you can convert the `.mbox` files in to `.eml` files with a [Free MBOX to EML utility.](http://www.outlookimport.com/downloads/mbox-eml-extractor.exe) You can then import these `.eml` files in to Outlook. Then from Outlook you can export the mailbox in to a `.pst` that can then be imported in to Exchange. As you can probably already tell this is going to take a long time.

**Edit:**

As you are a moving to a new exchange environment I would look in to enforcing mailbox size limits and auto archiving. 10 GB mailboxes is abnormally large size from my experience.